# Avoid "magic strings" in databound web controls?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

Is there a way to bind data to controls using the properties being bound to them so re-factoring and typos aren't so much of an issue?

For example, instead of assigning field names to a drop-down list like `ddl.DataTextField = "FieldName"; ddl.DataValueField = "Id"`, I would hypothetically write `ddl.DataTextField = MyClass.FieldName; ddl.DataValueField = MyClass.Id;`.

Edit:

I'm thinking about having my objects implement an interface that has DataTextField and DataValueField (or similarly named) properties so, at the very least, my DDLs would be consistently bound.

This wouldn't help in the case of ListViews, GridViews, etc. though.

Comment: A troll answer is to tell you to switch to ASP.NET MVC and take advantage of strongly-typed model data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are thinking, but maybe it will help out.

```
private void PopulateDropDown( List<MyClass> myClassList )
{
    // Loop through myClassList.
    foreach ( MyClass m in myClassList )
    {
        // Add myClass to the drop down list.
        ListItem item = new ListItem( m.FieldName, m.Id.ToString() );
        ddl.Items.Add( item );
    }
}
```

Comment: It would certainly solve the problem but is a little cumbersome.